# Read text from image without using tesseract using python3

Tags: computer-vision, python-3.6, opencv, python

I have a task to read text from image(.png format). I researched that it is possibile using opencv module, tesseract_OCR application, pytesseract module.

As I am on a strict client environment I won't be able to install tesseract_OCR (.exe) application on the host.

I am searching for an approach if it can be done without installing this OCR application. Please suggest me the approach.

For example i have below image:

[image]

I want out put as a text:

img=IMG.Convert('RGBA')

Comment: This image seems to be a screen copy or similar, no a picture. Too bad that you can't just parse the original source instead of "reverse engineering".

Comment: The quality of this image is so good that you can apply simple template matching technique to recognize your characters. I don't know a readily available open code for this though.